# Using Eclipse as Node.JS Remote Debugger (Connection Refused)

Tags: eclipse, node.js, remote-debugging, nodeclipse

I've used the Using Eclipse as Node Applications Debugger (https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger) to attempt to remotely debug a node script. My environment consists of a MAC OSX (version 10.9.4) client on which I've successfully installed Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600 and a Debain Wheezy Linux VM (VBOX 4.3.14). The firewall is correctly configured and both environment have the latest Node.JS installed (v0.10.31).

I was able to successfully debug a script locally with Eclipse on the MAC OSX client but I get a connection failure on the the attempt to debug remotely on the Debain Wheezy machine. 
*****Nodeclipse/chromedevtools failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM ( Check Help (F1) and Support http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support )*****
. Info:
Connection refused

I do run the "node --debug-brk dbgtest.js" on the  Debain Wheezy machine with the defualt port: 5858. The debugger starts successfully on port 5858:
**tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5858          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN**

I also tried the simple transparent TCP proxy script (tcpproxy.js) setup but it returns the same connection failure.

I have also successfully setup port forwarding (**ssh -R 5858:127.0.0.1:5858 [user]@[Debian-Host-Name]**) to the Debain machine but this did not help.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to update two aspects of my environment: SSH tunneling & stop my firewall. I did use this URL for the SSH tunneling(http://manas.tungare.name/blog/ssh-port-forwarding-on-mac-os-x/) and this URL to disable the firewall (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-iptables-stop/). These updates did not resolve the failed connection issue.

Comment: I was finally able to get the remote debugger to work via SSH Tunneling (http://www.engadget.com/2006/03/21/how-to-ssh-tunnels-for-secure-network-access/).  I followed the instructions found in this article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445534/how-to-remote-debug-node-js-with-phpstorm).

Answer (score 0):

Nodeclipse is using modified chromedevtools (version number 0.3.9).

For remote debugging I would suggest first to try 0.3.8 version of chromedevtools from https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/ (installed in other Eclipse instance) following instuctions already mentioned https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger

As co-author of Nodeclipse, I invite to co-work on enabling remote debugging with Nodeclipse https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/